# Eclipse Android is gone

Tags: android, eclipse

Without doing anything today I opened Eclipse and no longer had the Android Developer Tools installed. That is, in the Window tab should appear below all the options Android SDK and AVD Manager Manager.

It is as if it was deleted. However, I return to complete all the steps to install it and still do not see Android options. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: If you go to Window -> Preferences do you get an Android tab?

Comment: No, the Android tab of Preferences has also disappeared. I do not understand what happened. I'm desperate because I'm seeing that the only option will be to lower an eclipse of the whole new set and I do not like it because I have many projects in this eclipse with your jar etc. ..

Comment: The same thing happened to me a few months back. I tried restarting Eclipse and when it reopened it didn't recognize any of my Android projects. In the end I had to download a new copy, reinstall all the android stuff and start fresh. I tried to find an answer but after quite a while I just gave in and downloaded a new version of Eclipse. I don't know how you handled your Jars but if you set them up as User Libraries you can just re-import them to the library and all of the projects that referenced that User Library will have access to it again.

Comment: When you downloaded and installed eclipse/android sdk do you know where each component in your filesystem lives? Eclipse doesn't have a Windows installer. A friend 'installed' eclipse in the Downloads directory and when it cleaned up, he lost it.

Comment: have you tried starting with eclipse with -clean command line arg? that should work as long as you installed Android properly in the first place. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

try starting eclipse with the

```
- clean
```

option.

if you are on windows, amend  the start icon for eclipse to pass the

```
- clean
```

as a command line arg